# Power Automate SQL Server Email

Tags: sql-server, power-automate, onpremises-gateway

I'm trying to do the following action in power automate:

perform a query via SQL Server (on premises gateway).
filter table table1
where the field1 field is not empty.
where the date1 field has passed more than 7 days from today.
this table1 has an id__ppl field

look for this id_ppl in another table, table2, and relate it to the name_ppl and email_ppl.

send an email with a table with columns
field1, name_ppl and email_ppl.

I don't know how to perform this lookupvalue within automate, suggestions on how to proceed?